Error en ventana dataset and query dialog Jaspersoft studio vs.6.21.2
Estimada comunidad tengo una consulta por favor y necesito de vuestra ayuda. Ya logré establecer conexión con mi BD desde Jaspersoft Studio versión 6.21.2 por medio de un Data Adapter. Al ingresar a la ventana Dataset and Query Dialog me muestra del lado izquierdo mis schemas y tablas, pero en el lado derecho donde se supone que debo escribir mi query para poder leer los campos me sale un mensaje de error que dice: "mismatched input '' expecting 'SELECT'" y no me permite ingresar mi query ¿A qué se debe y cómo lo puedo solucionar? 

Encontré la solución estimada comunidad. Al final no se veía el puntero para ingresar el query pero si permitió ingresarlo. Gracias.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
